# How to pass two sets of posts to wordpress template

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Our website currently has functionality that allows us to choose content for a newsletter and it generates two RSS feeds based on the selected data - one for articles chosen to appear in the newsletter and another for products that were chosen to appear in the newsletter.  We then use those two RSS feeds to assemble our newsletter in the tools at our email service provider.

Now we're moving to a new email service provider that doesn't offer this RSS functionality, so we need to change the way wordpress renders it so that there is one template that combines both the products and article data into one formatted newsletter.  And being a wordpress newbie, I'm having trouble understanding how I can pass two sets of posts to the template for rendering.

The way it currently works with the RSS feeds, is there is a switch in the query to pull the content to change the query depending on whether the feed being viewed is the products feed or the articles feed.  This querying is altered via the "pre_get_posts" filter.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions of how these two sets of data can be combined into one template.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Most everything I'm reading is showing that each page template in wordpress is responsible for rendering one list.  Is there a way that I can achieve the goal of getting both the list of posts (articles) and product posts, then combining them into one query and somehow in the data indicating via a custom property that a given post is of type "article" or "product" so that they could be dealt with separately in the template?  Any ideas are welcome!

Comment: Another idea is to assume that the first X posts are "articles" and the remaining ones are "products" (these are all posts just different in the taxonomy applied to them).  This way, in the template I can know to display the first X as articles and treat the others as products.  I imagine I can do that via the existing "pre_get_posts" action, doing a query for each type, return a query from pre_get_posts - like this $query->set( 'post__in', $assigned_ids ); - how can I be sure that the query returns them in the same order they were added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless anyone has a better solution, I think the way I'm going to approach this is to modify my "pre_get_posts" action to do two queries - first for articles and next for products - and then create a new query using post__in and orderby=>'post__in' which should preserve the order in which they were added to the query.

This way, I'll know to treat the first X posts as articles and the remainder as products.

This article was helpful in finding the solution of orderby=>'post__in' : http://www.tamaraolsondesigns.com/tips-and-tricks/how/